# Connect to Cassandra Cluster fails with an IP address - WSO2 BAM

Tags: cassandra, wso2, wso2-bam

I am using WSO2 BAM 2.3.0. In that I use Home -> Manage -> Cassandra Explorer -> Connect to Cluster to explore the my data in Cassandra cluster. Up to some point I used the local Cassandra cluster with Connection Url as localhost:9161 and it works fine.

Later I wanted to explore the same cluster(Which runs on remote server) using a locally running BAM instance. I used the IP Address:9161 as Connection Url. But it failed with following error in console,

```
[2013-08-25 13:44:19,320] ERROR {me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager} -  Could not start connection pool for host IPAddress(IPAddress):9161
```

Then I go to the remote server's BAM management console and entered the same server's IP address as Connection Url. But there also it fails. When I change the IP address to localhost, it works fine. What has gone wrong here?

Also I did this because I tried to run a Hive Query on my local machine by connecting to above mentioned Server's Cassandra Cluster. It failed with some exceptions saying couldn't connect to the Cassandra.

Comment: I don't think that you can access that internal cassandra database through a URL. If you running hive script locally then why you need BAM cassandra cluster? You can setup an external cassandra. Otherwise use the BAM to execute the hive script.

Comment: It works for the localhost:9161. In my case localhost=IP_address and IP_address:9161 fails. Why that happen?

Comment: Can you check whether you can connect to the above port (in the remote server) within the local machine. (You can use telnet for this i.e `telnet IP_ADDRESS PORT`)

Answer (score 3):

You can access. You must edit cassandra.yaml file in BAM_HOME/repository/conf/etc.

Change the listen address and rpc_address to your ip address.

Then in master-datasources.xml for WSO2BAM_CASSANDRA_DB use the ip address in the url.